# refresh container without refreshing page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

By using this `<?php echo date('r'); ?>`, is there any way i can refresh simple container (span where my time is echo) without refreshing the page  [image: Here this is my page i am displaying date and time here]

Comment: well you can also use javascript for that purpose

Comment: PHP cannot modify a page once it's been sent to the client. Anything you end up doing will either involve javascript or page refreshes.

Comment: please understand, server side and client side scope first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send AJAX request periodically to a PHP file which echos date.

```
(function worker() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'backend.php', 
    success: function(data) {
      $('.result').html(data);
    },
    complete: function() {
      // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
      setTimeout(worker, 5000);
    }
  });
})();
```

Call this `worker()` function on the div of the date.

`backend.php`:

```
<?php
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // This is just a sample date format. YOUR DATE FORMAT.
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <iframe src="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i4gbn2wi/n1763/tt0/tw0/ts1/tb4" frameborder="0" width="132" height="34"></iframe>
```

Try this